# Parent website blocks iframe in child iframe

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

I have a very weird problem and I haven't found the answer for it.

I have a website on domain a.com. On this website I have a child iframe which is served on subdomain.a.com. CSP on a.com allows the loading of this iframe via `frame-src subdomain.a.com;`

The iframe subdomain.a.com can load it's own iframes on various domains (example.com etc.). subdomain.a.com has only this directive in CSP: `frame-ancestors a.com;`. Here I don't have any frame-src directives, because I need to allow any iframe.

The problem is, that `subdomain.a.com` is embedded without problems, but any iframes in `subdomain.a.com` are blocked by `a.com` because CSP in `a.com` does not allow `example.com`.

Why is this happening? Is this a feature of CSP, that it is inherited to iframes on same top domain?

### What I have tried.

1. I changed the `subdomain.a.com` to another top level domain `subdomain.a.xyz` and the problem persists.
2. In both cases I tried adding `frame-src *;` on `subdomain.a.com` and `subdomain.a.xyz`. Still to no avail.

Here is a drawing to avoid confusion.
[image]

Notes:

- There is some message passing between a.com and subdomain.a.com iframe.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The answer can probably be found in the HTTP headers of the inner iframe. Can you please add them to the question.

Comment: I think I figured it out why this is happening. I may be wrong still.
The child iframe on subdomain.a.com performs a redirect. Probably with window.location. 
The new url is probably checked against CSP rules.
Disclaimer: We are trying to integrate a payment provider with very bad DX.

Comment: Yeah if the domains of the ifrane and parent are in anyway different, then you can not directly access one from the other. The only option is to use `postMessage()`.